# Is it possible to have 2 menu items (AppBar), one aligned to the left, one to the right in android?

Tags: android

I would like to have an App bar with two items one aligned to the left, one to the right, I have done some research but nothing found. Just changing layout_direction to RTL or LTR.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
        android:title="find"
        app:showAsAction="always" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dots"
        android:title="help"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

this is my main menu which is inflated in the nav host activity and used in all remaining fragments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that this video might help you out, hope that this is what you are looking for. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oh4YOj9VkVE

Comment: I want one in the left one in the right, the title is clear. this video doesn't help me, thanks anyway.

Comment: No, Till now it is not possible

Comment: It's not a good practice at all. try to have BottomNavigationMenu or Drawer Menu beside AppBar Menu

Comment: it's required to be like this... My HostActivity right now has an AppbarLayout with an imageButton at the left as "fake menu item" and then I am inflating "rigth menu" in fragments so UI it's OK but I cannot control the left menu item in fragments as it's controlled in HostActivity. Any better solution?